# Inlining SVG filters as data URI

Tags: html, css, svg, data-uri, svg-filters

I'm trying to add a SVG filter using a data URI in the CSS but cannot get the effects applied to my image.

It seems that it should be supported as both data URI and SVG filters are supported in all major browser according to "caniuse". The filter works just fine if I save it as a SVG file and link to the file in the css instead.

I've tried with encoding the SVG as base64 and url encoding the file as well but to no avail.

The following is a example of such filter making the image to which the filter is applied black and white.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="light">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="grayscale--light"
            values="1 0 0 0 0
                    1 0 0 0 0
                    1 0 0 0 0
                    0 0 0 1 0">
        </feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

After encoding the SVG I create a class with the following style

```
.grayscale--light {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,base64encodedString")
}
```

And in my HTML

```
<img src="/path/to/my/image.jpg" class="grayscale--light">
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong or is it not supported anymore? All articles I find on the topic is from around 2014.

Comment: It isn't supported and edge barely supports svg. You can still greyscale the image using canvas. https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-grayscale-image-colors-tutorial/

Comment: Please provide a minimum verifiable test case. You are not showing the encoding you are using. [Typically you would need a fragment ID to reference a filter, so I don't know how you're getting the filter to work in a separate svg file without that. Also that's not a true greyscale filter - it's a red-channel filter - it copies red channel values into the blue and green channel and discards the existing blue and green values (it will give you very black skies, for example)

Comment: The grayscale is just a minimal example. I'm creating a a filter with a combination of feColorMatrix and feComponentTransfers. And normally I would just put them in a .svg file <filter id="filterID"> and reference the filter with an ID filter: url(path/to/filter.svg#filterID). However I'm trying to create the filters dynamically and that's why I need the filters inline as a data-uri. I've tried to recreate an example at https://jsfiddle.net/57dyw33m/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you would have to reference the `filter` id at the end of the data URI, like so: `...VyPg0KPC9zdmc+#filterID)`. Now it works in Firefox, <del>but not in Chrome which throws an error:</del>

*Older* versions of Chrome may throw an error (thanks @Daniel Weiner):

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL (...) from frame with URL <URL>. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

So Chrome doesn't like the data URI, and wants a proper URL with a domain that matches the current site. There is a way to do that: Instead of data-URI-encoding the SVG, put it in a `Blob` and generate a URL for it in JavaScript:

```
const svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filterID"> ... </svg>',
      blob = new Blob([svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml' }),
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

myImage.style.filter = `url('${url}#filterID')`;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ec0z2rq/

Comment: I guess this is the right answer! Thank you so much! apparently the support isn't very good at the moment. What I was trying to do was a postCSS plugin and therefor only really had access to the CSS file hence the inline SVG fitlers. I guess the difference between a javascript solution and SVG filter in the DOM isn't worth it performance wise and if I had to choose I would go with the HTML solution rather than the javascript one.

But your solution worked in the browsers I tested it in so I will accept your answer

Comment: In 2020, this works on Chrome. Example: https://codepen.io/DanielWeiner/full/YzwLNxR. I also tested it with <animate>, and that doesn't seem to work with inline data URL SVG filters.