# CSS clip-path doesn't stretch with path()

Tags: html, css, svg, clip

I'm trying to use the [`clip-path` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) with an `path` value. But for some reason, the clipping isn't scaling with the element, like it does using an HTML svg as `url()`.

Is there a way to make `path()` behave like `url()` does (stretching the clipping)

NOTE: i also tried to generate an [url-encoded svg](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) and used `clip-path: url('data:image...')` but it doesn't seem to work

```css
.heart {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.svg {
  clip-path: url(#myPath)
}

.path {
  clip-path: path('M15,45 A30,30,0,0,1,75,45 A30,30,0,0,1,135,45 Q135,90,75,130 Q15,90,15,45 Z')
}
```

```html
<div class="heart svg">With SVG</div>
<div class="heart path">With PATH</div>

<svg>
  <clipPath id="myPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M0.5,1
      C 0.5,1,0,0.7,0,0.3
      A 0.25,0.25,1,1,1,0.5,0.3
      A 0.25,0.25,1,1,1,1,0.3
      C 1,0.7,0.5,1,0.5,1 Z" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5618

Comment: No. All you can do is use a vector editor to scale your `path()` so that it is the right size (180 x 100).

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by scaling the content down to the size of the clip path, then clipping it, then scaling it back up

```css
.heart {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    width: calc(var(--desired-width) * 1px);
    height: calc(var(--desired-height) * 1px);
}
.heart-clip {
    clip-path: path("M0.5,1 C 0.5,1,0,0.7,0,0.3 A 0.25,0.25,1,1,1,0.5,0.3 A 0.25,0.25,1,1,1,1,0.3 C 1,0.7,0.5,1,0.5,1 Z");
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}
.heart-scale-vars {
    --path-width: 1;
    --path-height: 1;
    --desired-width: 180;
    --desired-height: 100;
}
.scale-pre {
    transform: scale(
        calc(var(--path-width) / var(--desired-width)),
        calc(var(--path-height) / var(--desired-height))
    );
    transform-origin: top left;
}
.scale-post {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: scale(
        calc(var(--desired-width) / var(--path-width)),
        calc(var(--desired-height) / var(--path-height))
    );
}
.scale-postpost {
    width: calc(var(--desired-width) * 1px);
    height: calc(var(--desired-height) * 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="heart-scale-vars scale-postpost"><div class="scale-post heart-clip"><div class="scale-pre heart">With PATH</div></div></div>
```

or by using a url encoded svg as a mask

```css
.heart {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
}
.heart-mask {
    mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpath d='M.5 1C.5 1 0 .7 0 .3A .25.25 1 1 1 .5.3A.25 .25 1 1 1 1 .3C1 .7 .5 1 .5 1Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1 1' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpath d='M.5 1C.5 1 0 .7 0 .3A .25.25 1 1 1 .5.3A.25 .25 1 1 1 1 .3C1 .7 .5 1 .5 1Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="heart heart-mask">With MASK</div>
```

Comment: Yeah i was using the URL encoded solution earlier, but the clip-path `path()` is way more ellegant and clean, but for now it's the only solution i've found. The scale solution doesn't work for a fluid element, only with a preset size.

Comment: do you know if clip-path supports encoded url?

Comment: seems like encoded svg urls with ids work for svg filters (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523461/inlining-svg-filters-as-data-uri#comment111121832_49535174)), but i wasn't able to get it to work for clip-path